# Same behavior, different synthesis outputs, state machine coding style in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, state-machines, synthesis

In an old course book on VHDL I've been revising, the author discussed the effect of coding style on the actual synthesis output of state machines. The example discussed in the book is a classic Mealy machine with synchronous outputs.

```vhdl
process(clk, resetn)
begin
        if resetn = '0' then
            state <= s0;
            q <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            case state is
                when s0 =>
                    if a = '1' then
                        state <= s1;
                        q <= "1001";
                    end if;
                when s1 =>
                    if a = '0' then
                        state <= s2;
                        q <= "1100";
                    end if;
                when s2 =>
                    if a = '1' then
                        state <= s3;
                        q <= "1111";
                    end if;
                when s3 =>
                    if a = '0' then
                        state <= s0;
                        q <= "0000";
                    end if;
            end case;
        end if;
end process;
```

In the above code, the output `q` is not assigned a definite value in every state/input combination. There will be instances where the old value of `q` is kept.
The author emphases the importance of assigning a definite value to a state-machine's output at every clock cycle. From a functional perspective, the code in the first example is nevertheless correct.

In the second example, the code is almost the same, but the output `q` is assigned a value in every state/input combination.

```vhdl
process (clk, resetn)
begin
        if resetn = '0' then
            state <= s0;
            q <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            case state is
                when s0 =>
                    if a = '1' then
                        state <= s1;
                        q <= "1001";
                    else
                        q <= "0000";
                    end if;
                when s1 =>
                    if a = '0' then
                        state <= s2;
                        q <= "1100";
                    else
                        q <= "1001";
                    end if;
                when s2 =>
                    if a = '1' then
                        state <= s3;
                        q <= "1111";
                    else
                        q <= "1100";
                    end if;
                when s3 =>
                    if a = '0' then
                        state <= s0;
                        q <= "0000";
                    else
                        q <= "1111";
                    end if;
            end case;
        end if;
end process;
```

The author states that, although both designs maintain the same behavior, the synthesis result is not identical. The first design is 12 gates larger! The second design optimizes away 3 gates per output pin. I synthesized both descriptions in Quartus and observed that the first design seemed to contain a couple of more Muxes.

However my question is: is it a completely straightforward task to guess the difference, in exact number of gates, between the two designs or does it require a pen and paper and doing some of the optimizations the synthesis tool normally does (Karnaugh, etc) by hand. I can't see where the *3 gates / output* come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is width of the *state* register? Assuming its 2 bits, the second example is different in that the output of *q* is defined for every combination of inputs, so it's only combinational logic. In the 1st example *q* needs to be kept in a register from previous cycle since it's not defined for every combination of inputs (I think the synthesizer will not go that far as to determine the value of *q* is dependent on *state*). In System Verilog, the constructs *always_ff* and *always_comb* help flag these kinds of differences at synthesis.

Edit: screenshot of Xilinx Vivado RTL schematic added
Each block of logic highlighted is combinational, with some truth table N input bits by M output bits. There is no way of predicting the number of gates this mux will synthesize down to without doing the optimisations yourself with K-maps and whatnot (it might also be using logic common to other combinational logic circuits, e.g. CE signal for *state* and *q* are identical). What this actually compiles down to is dependent on the target architecture (how many inputs your FPGA lookup table blocks have or what library cells are available when laying out an ASIC).

Case 1:
CE logic: takes inputs *a* (1bit), *state* (2b), outputs CE (1b). Truth table is 3b wide input by 1b wide output
Next q logic: same set of inputs as above, 3b input, 4b output

Case 2:
Next q logic: 3b input, 4b output

Another thing, even though the "Next q logic" table has the same size, the CE logic makes it so the output doesn't matter for most of the combinations so can be optimised much further.

[image]
[image]

Implementation:

1st case needs 6 LUTs, 4 D-flipflops with CE.

2nd case: 5 LUTs, 6 D-flipflops with CE. It has separate registers for state and q

Maybe someone else can explain what's going on.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The flipflop is present in both examples as the output `q` is clocked (synchronous). However, I think the difference resides in the number of multiplexer inferred by the tool. The `state` logic is identical in both examples, so I doubt that it affects the synthesis result.